# Is .unbind().click(function() {...}) a good practice?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I'm talking about the following:

```
.unbind().click(function () {
    // Do something
}
```

It looks a bit dodgy to me, however it makes sense: the developer wants to first remove any events bound to the element and then bind a click event.

Is there a better solution for this issue? Or correct my way of thinking.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not really good practice, because you do not control which click events get unbound. There are two different approaches to improve this:

### Use event namespaces (faster)

You can use a namespace to control you unbind just the click event you're going to bind again:

```
$(selector).off('click.namespace').on('click.namespace', function(e) { //...
```

### Use classes (fastest)

Use classes added to the link to mark it as registered (this does not unbind previously bound events, but it helps preventing multiple event bindings, which is the issue in most cases you would use `off` (unbind) before `on` (bind):

```
$(selector).not('.registered').addClass('registered').on('click', function(e) { //...
```

You can even turn this into a little sexy plugin, writing:

```
$.fn.register = function(register_class) {
  register_class || (register_class = 'registered'); // lets you control the class
  return this.not('.' + register_class).addClass(register_class);
};
```

Like this, you can just call `register` on every selector:

```
$(selector).register().on('click', function(e) { //...
```

Or with a specific class, if «registered» is taken:

```
$(selector).register('special_handler_registered').on('click', function(e) { //...
```

### Performance?

If you wonder about the performance of the different handlers:

**[Check out this performance test here](http://jsperf.com/rebindvsregisterjquery2/2)**

Comment: Hi @BeatRichartz, this looks interesting, but I'm missing something. In the performance tests, a link is taken and, in the first case, unbounded and bounded again a handler for the click event, while in the second one, is added a class and bound a handler for click. So, in the latter, you are not unbinding anything, are you? I'm sure I'm wrong in something, but can't see it

Comment: Hey @davids, the second test case uses the `$.fn.register` plugin i mentioned in my answer. It does not necessarily unbind click handlers, but it prevents double-registering the click handlers, which is the issue in most cases you would use `off` (unbind) before `on` (bind). It's another way of knowing whether a link has event handlers bound to it. There may be the case where you would want to unbind just all click events, but in my opinion, it's bad practice to just unbind events just because you do not know if some handler is bound somewhere.

Comment: Ok. I followed the unbind/bind approach in PhoneGap/jQuery Mobile applications, where the Html never gets reloaded and most handlers depend on the current context of the app, so I guess in that particular case I can't use something like the register plugin :S

Answer (score 2):

I followed this approach whenever I had to "renew" some button, link, ect., behavior, and I think there's nothing wrong with it.
But be aware that with your code you'd be removing every handler attached to the element(s). So, instead:

```
$(selector).unbind('click').click(function(){
    // do something
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, at least it is good practice to specify which event handlers should be unbinded. So if there was some click event hendler and we want to unbind only it, then we can use `unbind('click')`.

Answer (score 1):

As there can be some other handlers in addition to yours, it make sense to use namespaces.

```
$(selector).off('click.myns').on('click.myns', function() {....})

or 

$(selector).unbind('click.myns').bind('click.myns',function() {...})
```

This way you will only touch your own handler and not some others, for instance added by jquery plugins

Answer (score 1):

I usually try to used named event functions where ever possible in order to be able to unbind them explicitly:

```
$('a').unbind('click.myfunc').bind('click.myfunc', function(evt) { ... });
```

This way you could add this binding to an init-function that could be executed multiple times (handy for situations where you can't use delegate for whatever reason).

In general I would't try to unbind every event or even every handler of a certain event if I don't need to.

I'm also trying to stay current and replace all the bind/unbind calls with on/off ;-)